# Kubernetes AAD system managed identity?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-kubernetes-service

I've looked all over Google, and everything seems to point to usee-assigned managed identity, which is great, but a hassle to maintain.

Does anything support system-assigned Identity, at a pod level? Where it will manage assignment of the ID for me?

(I guess it's not possible due to the nature of pod being transient?)